# What is the difference?

Tags: php, cakephp

I try out CakePHP. I follow this [Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/de/view/339/Deleting-Posts) and can't find out why this code doesn't work. The code from the tutorial works fine.

```
echo $html -> link('Löschen', array('action' => 'delete', 'id' => $post['Post']['id']), null, 'Sind Sie sicher?' );
```

---

Its a problem with the "ö". Without the "ö" everything works fine.

Comment: See http://bit.ly/aTLnAA

Comment: How does the "not working" manifests itself?

Comment: What's the resulting HTML from this (View Source) and what "doesn't work"?

Comment: FrediWeber didn't you get any solution from below answers? if yes then mark and up-vote that answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `__()` as this will allow more translations and stuff, it might fix your issue. Either that, or convert it to an HTML entity.

Comment: @FrediWeber   didn't you get any solution from all  answers? please cross-check and if got the answer then mark and up-vote that answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling `iconv.internal_encoding = UTF-8` in your php.ini file to handle non-standard characters like the ö there you're using.

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work too. Maybe it's a server problem.

Comment: @FrediWeber   didn't you get any solution from all  answers? please cross-check and if got the answer then mark and up-vote that answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
link(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $htmlAttributes = array(), string $confirmMessage = false, boolean $escapeTitle = true)
```

try setting escapeTitle to false?

Answer (score -1):

Consider oe instead of o with an umlaut